# Add chosen module to angular app

Tags: angularjs, typescript, jquery-chosen

I am working on AngularJS app.I am using typescript.
The problem is that i am trying to add new module which is angular-chosen.But i get error chosen not a function.In app.module.ts 
what i did is in app.module.ts:

```
Import "angular-chosen-localytics";
angular.module('app',['localytics.directives']).
```

Then i tried to call the chosen.js in index.html but i get the error "can't get file " .I verified that the file is available under node_modules/dist directory.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just forgot to add it in your *.html file:

```
<script src=".../angular.min.js>
....
<script src=".../angular-chosen-localytics/dist/angular-chosen.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried to do that.But I get error 404.I can't access them from node_modules.In fact I am working  with webpack and es6

Answer (score 0):

`angular-chosen-localytics` is not supporting the ES6 modules.

You can try `require/import` of `'angular-chosen-localytics/dist/angular-chosen'` file, but I guess it will not go very far as it needs `jquery` ($) at the top level.